# 'HTTP headers is not in the correct format' error when creating Azure Container using Python SDK

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage, azure-sdk-python

I'm trying to create an Azure blob container using Python SDK with the below code. I'm getting an 'ErrorCode:InvalidHeaderValue' in the response.

I'm using the 'ConnectionString' from 'Access Keys' section from the Azure Portal of the storage account. And I don't think the connection is the issue since this line works ok `blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)`.

I used a clean venv for this and below are the library versions
azure-core==1.10.0
azure-storage-blob==12.7.1

```
import os
import yaml
from azure.storage.blob import ContainerClient, BlobServiceClient

def load_config():
    dir_root = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    with open (dir_root + "/config.yaml", "r") as yamlfile:
        return yaml.load(yamlfile, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)

config = load_config()
connection_string = config['azure_storage_connectionstring']

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
blob_service_client.create_container('testing')
```

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/anojshrestha/Documents/codes/gen2lake/project_azure/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_container_client.py", line 292, in create_container
    **kwargs)
  File "/Users/anojshrestha/Documents/codes/gen2lake/project_azure/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_generated/operations/_container_operations.py", line 134, in create
    raise HttpResponseError(response=response, model=error)
azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError: Operation returned an invalid status 'The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
.......
azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError: The value for one of the HTTP headers is not in the correct format.
RequestId:5X-601e-XXXX00ab-5368-f0c05f000000
Time:2021-01-22T02:43:22.3983063Z
ErrorCode:InvalidHeaderValue
Error:None
HeaderName:x-ms-version
HeaderValue:2020-04-08```
````

Comment: Could you please enable the log to get the detailed error message :  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/azure-sdk-logging?

Comment: Same story here. Looks like a bug in azure-storage-blob. I reverted to 12.6.0 and that fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks @kopaczew. You're right! Rolling back the version fixed my issue. I'll see if there's an existing bug raised.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need to reinstall. You can get around this issue by setting your `api_version` variable when instantiating any of the clients.

For example:

```
blob = BlobServiceClient(
    account_url="https://MY_BLOB_STORAGE.blob.core.windows.net",
    credential="MY_PRIMARY_KEY",
    api_version="2019-12-12", #or api_version='2020-02-10'
)
```

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/16193

Comment: Thanks @Tamer! Looks like your answer was verified by someone. I'll choose your answer.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @kopaczew, reverting the azure_storage_blob to 12.6.0 version fixed my issue. It does seem to be some sort of bug with the latest azure-storage-blob library. Unfortunately, the aforementioned issue is not limited to the create_container call. Answering my own question in case this helps someone else in a similar situation.

How I fixed my issue:

1. Removed my previous venv environment (reinstalling itself caused some issues when importing the azure library)
2. Created new venv
3. `pip install azure-storage-bob==12.6.0`